# How to detect that all subscribers to an event have responded

Tags: msmq, masstransit

I am currently investigating Mass Transit. I have written a simple sample based on the Starbucks sample.

I have the following saga:

```
    Define(() =>
    {
        Initially(
            When(ReportRequest)
                .Then((saga, message) => saga.ProcessReportRequest(message))
                .TransitionTo(WaitingForReportToComplete)
            );

        During(WaitingForReportToComplete, When(ReportComplete)
            .Then((saga, message) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Report Complete for '{0}'", saga.Name);
                    saga.CompleteReportRequest(message);
                })
                .Complete()
            );
    });
```

The problem I am having is that I have X subscribers to the `ReportRequest` event and each subscriber create a small part of the report. Therefore, for the report to be considered complete all subscribers need to have issued a `ReportComplete` event. At the moment the first subscriber to complete issues a `ReportComplete` event and the saga then also completes.

**How do I set up a saga so that it waits for all X subscribers to respond to a given message before completing?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347748/masstransit-and-rabbit-mq-how-many-consumers-are-connected/20351316#20351316 ; while you can inspect the pipeline usefully with MSMQ, unlikely RabbitMQ, it's still not how you should construct the solution. This isn't what pub/sub is for, need to bring it into your application level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's a two step solution:

- first you need to "enlist" all the subscribers that you expect to participate. This could be a static/shared information, maintained outside of the saga, depending on your scenario.
- only when you received "complete" from all enlisted participants you can move to Complete state. You can instruct the saga imperatively to move to another state.